# 2D lookup table creation in python

Tags: python, matrix, tuples

How can I create a variable in python `Matrix_Table` holding value of lookup table like:
[image]

And also how is it possible to obtain the corresponding value present in (t1,i4)???

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this :

```
a = [[1, 5, 7, 8, 3],
     [4, 6, 4, 5, 7],
     [5, 6, 5, 5, 7],
     [4, 7, 2, 7, 2],
     [1, 3, 2, 2, 7],
     [1, 5, 7, 2, 4],
     [1, 6, 4, 2, 1]]

i1 = a[0]
i2 = a[1]
i3 = a[2]
i4 = a[3]
i5 = a[4]
i6 = a[5]
i7 = a[6]




print(i1[4])
```

This would print the 1st row and 5th column producing the value of 3.

But note that t1 = [0], t2 = [1], t3 = [2], t4 = [3], t5 = [4]. I set all the i1, i2, i3, etc. values to their row values but you would have to use [0], [1], [2] to find their respective column.

Answer (score 0):

For very simple purposes you could use builtin map for storing 2D table:

```
class Matrix_Table:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__data = {}

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        try:
            return self.__data[idx]
        except KeyError:
            return 0

    def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
        self.__data[idx] = value

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__data.items())

m = Matrix_Table()
m[1, 2] = 10
m[2, 3] = 20
print(m[1, 2])  # prints 10
print(m[1, 1])  # prints 0
print(len(m))   # prints 2
```